# Can I do on-chip debugging on atmega328p with gdb (command line)?

Tags: arduino, debugging, atmega328p, openocd, gdb

Is there a way of doing on-chip debugging of Arduino Uno (atmega328p) with gdb on the command line? I'm looking for something simplistic and excluding IDE solutions like Eclipse and Atmel Studio. I use VIM for programming and compile my code with a cmake build system provided by [queezythegreat](https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake).

I had a look at my options but didn't get a clear answer to what tools I would need. Would gdb alone be enough or do I need something like [openOCD](https://openocd.org)?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/how-do-i-debug-a-arduino-uno-with-gdb-on-a-linux-pc

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had already looked at that post and the question/answers only consider debugging of MCU simulations. Also, the question is about six years old so I hoped to get an answer with currently available tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVR debugwire in Linux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/avr-debugwire-in-linux) which actually has the details